# How exactly do you hook up 16 drives to this RAID card?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, storage, sas

http://www.lsi.com/products/raid-controllers/pages/megaraid-sas-9240-8i.aspx#tab/tab1

I'm utterly confused only because I'm not versed as well in enterprise storage capability and solutions. The description says the card supports 16 drives in RAID, but, it only has 2 ports and includes 2 cables each with 1 SAS to 4 SATA connectors. That's still only 8 drives. So where are they getting the 16 from and how would you attach 16 drives? I haven't seen a 1 SAS to 8 SATA cable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I attach more hard drives to my hardware RAID card?](http://superuser.com/questions/323078/how-do-i-attach-more-hard-drives-to-my-hardware-raid-card)

Comment: You need SAS-> SATA breakout cables, or a proper SAS expander. Also see this ServerFault Q&A: [How exactly does a SAS SFF-8087 breakout cable work? + RAID/connection questions](http://serverfault.com/questions/510442/how-exactly-does-a-sas-sff-8087-breakout-cable-work-raid-connection-questions)